# How to pull Newsstand apps out of Newsstand, or else put other apps into Newsstand?

Tags: folders, ios, newsstand

I was happy to find that in iOS 7, Newsstand can finally be put into another folder. However, Newsstand, Passbook, FaceTime and the other default factory apps still cannot be removed from the phone (without jailbreaking). This is perfectly fine -- we can throw these apps on the last screen and ignore them, or at least that's the way it should be.

In fact, my New York Times app is stuck inside Newsstand and I cannot take it out. It is the only app in there. Ideally, I'd like to pull it out, throw it in my custom "News" folder, and throw Newsstand on screen infinity, never to be noticed again.

But I'd take another solution: Adding all my "news" apps to Newsstand. Unfortunately, Newsstand will not accept these apps (NPR, AP, Instapaper).

Is there a way to put all these apps in the same, single folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Note: with the release of iOS 9 you can now pull New York Times and other apps from Newsstand.

What you ask isn't possible on stock iOS 7. Newstand subscriptions are not treated as full fledged apps or Safari bookmarks that can be placed arbitrarily on the springboard.

Comment: NYTimes Mobile [tells me](https://twitter.com/nytimesmobile/status/385092843347255296): The NYTimes iOS apps are only available in Newsstand.

Comment: The OP is hardly asking to do this 'arbitrarily'.

Comment: Huzzah @samthebrand - late but Apple delivers